# Is it possible to expect an RSpec double be called twice with varying values?

Tags: rspec-mocks

On RSpec's [mock docs](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.8/rspec-mocks/) I found
    expect(double).to receive(:msg).exactly(3).times.and_return(value1, value2, value3)
    # returns value1 the first time, value2 the second, etc`

If I do the same `with` parameters, for ex.
    expect(double).to receive(:msg).exactly(3).times.with(value1, value2, value3)
RSpec naturally expects `msg` to be called with `value1, value2, value3` three times.
Is there a way to say `called the first time with value1, the second time with value 2, etc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.ordered`, like this:

```
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(value1).ordered
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(value2).ordered
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(value3).ordered
```